# Replace forward slash with space before and after only if no space in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have the following input:

```
aaa/bbb
ccc/ ddd
eee /fff
ggg / hhh
/iii/jjj/
```

I would like to make sure all forward slashes (Except for the ones in the end of a string) have a space before and after.  The result would be:

```
aaa / bbb
ccc / ddd
eee / fff
ggg / hhh
/iii / jjj/
```

So far I have the following regex:

```
(?<=\/)(?!$)
```

But this is still far from working.  Any help would be appreciated figuring out the correct regex for this.  The language is C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*(?<!^\s*)/(?!\s*$)\s*", " / ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%28%3f%3c!%5e%5cs*%29%2f%28%3f!%5cs*%24%29%5cs*&i=aaa%2fbbb%0d%0accc%2f+ddd%0d%0aeee+%2ffff%0d%0aggg+%2f+hhh%0d%0a%2fiii%2fjjj%2f&r=+%2f+&o=m)

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?<!^\s*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is start of a line followed with zero or more whitespaces immediately on the left
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?!\s*$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitespaces followed with end of line position immediately on the right
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

Or, another variation:

```cs
var output = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=(?<!^)/(?!\s|$))|(?=(?<!^|\s)/(?!$))", " ");
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%5e%29%2f%28%3f!%5cs%7c%24%29%29%7c%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3c!%5e%7c%5cs%29%2f%28%3f!%24%29%29&i=%2faaa%2fbbb%2f&r=+&o=m).

*Details*:

- `(?<=(?<!^)/(?!\s|$))` - a position right after a `/` that is neither at the start nor at the end of a string and that is not followed with a whitespace
- `|` - or
- `(?=(?<!^|\s)/(?!$))` - a position right before a `/` that is neither at the start nor at the end of a string and that is not preceded with a whitespace.

Comment: Wiktor, thank you very much that worked great!